# Truncate model property in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, truncate

Im currently using a truncate and texteditor in different way. And both is working fine but I facing this problem. I want to truncate a text inside the texteditor. T_T
**Im using truncate this way and its working**

```
@helper Truncate(string input, int length)
    {
    if (input.Length <= length)
    {
        @input
    }
    else
    {
        @input.Substring(0, length)<text>...</text>
    }
}


@foreach (var item in Model)
{       
        <div>
            @Truncate(item.DetailDescription, 400)
        </div>
}
```

**AND**

**Im declaring raw to call a texteditor this way and its also working fine**

```
@html.Raw(item.DetailDescription)
```

**PROBLEM: How could I possibly combine the two in a single function? Is this even possible T_T**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done like this one before. I did it this way.

```
@helper Truncate(string input, int length)
 {
   if (input.Length <= length) {
   @Html.Raw(input)
    } else {
    var thisString = input.Substring(0, length);
    @Html.Raw(thisString)
            }
 }
```

I combined raw inside the truncate helper then I call the Truncate this way

```
@Truncate(item.DetailDescription, 400)
```

Comment: cool I'm trying ssilas777 suggestions but your answer works faster. thanks. That answers it.. :)

Answer (score 6):

It's always better to put the business logic inside the model.

I would have done this in the model itself adding another property '`TruncatedDescription`'.

```
  public string TruncatedDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DetailDescription.Length > 400 ? this.DetailDescription.Substring(0, 400) + "..." : this.DetailDescription;
        }
    }
```

So you can use this in the View directly

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{       
        <div>
             item.TruncatedDescription
        </div>
}
```

If you are following this method, you can use `item.TruncatedDescription` in the text-editor with out help of `html.Row` as this won't be HTML encoded.

Comment: I dont have a problem with my truncate its only that I want to truncate the text inside the texteditor. But +1 for presenting me another method how to do it.. :)

Comment: I would have to agree that having the business logic in the model is definitely better than in the view.