# How to show intro text only in news website (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a function in my view:

```
@helper truncate(string input, int length)
{
    if (input.Length<=length)
    {
        @input;
    }
    else
    {
        @input.Substring(0,length)@:...
    }
}
```

If i write `@truncate("some word",50) =>` it worked
But i write `@truncate(item.Description, 50) =>` it error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Please help me to fix my problem or show me another way to show intro text only in my site

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, `item.Description` is not null?

Comment: some rows in Description are null.

Comment: so, you should check it, it must be not null.

Answer (score 0):

if input is null, then you get error `input.Length` and `input.Substring` lines. You should check, if it is not null.

```
@helper truncate(string input, int length)
{
    if(input == null)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        if (input.Length <= length)
        {
            @input;
        }
        else
        {
            @input.Substring(0,length)@:...
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT (after comment)**

you can use:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input , "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

**NOTE:** `Html.Raw` returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Comment: First, thank you so much. Now it work but how to remove html tag from my content. I wrote @truncate(Html.Raw(item.Description).ToString(), 100).

Comment: I use: @Html.Raw(input) in my function and @Truncate(item.Description, 400) for display result..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847844/truncate-model-property-in-asp-net-mvc. Anyway, thank you so much

Comment: but, "remove html tag" and "html encoded" are different things. as you say, anyway :) glad it helped :)